# Apps crashed with fatal exception

Tags: android

my friends help me do this android app, but i dont really know what is the actual problems here. Can you guys help me? I try to run the code in the android, but when i try to login in my app login menu, it crashes

Here is my Database Helper

```
package com.example.ikramhs.shoerack;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "login";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DB_TABLE = "create table user (id integer primary key autoincrement, " + "username text not null,password text not null;";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null,DB_VERSION) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion ){
        Log.w(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(),
                "Upgrading database from version" + oldVersion + "to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user");
        onCreate(database);
    }
}
```

and here is my Database Adapter file

```
package com.example.ikramhs.shoerack;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class DatabaseAdapter {

    private static final String LOGIN_TABLE = "user";
    public static final String COL_ID = "id";
    public static final String COL_USERNAME = "username";
    public static final String COL_PASSWORD = "password";

    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

    public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public DatabaseAdapter open() {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context) ;
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }

    public long createUser (String username, String password)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = createUserTableContentValues ( username,password );
        return database.insert(LOGIN_TABLE,null,initialValues);
    }

    public Cursor fetchUser(String username, String password)
    {
        Cursor myCursor = database.query(LOGIN_TABLE, new String[] {COL_ID, COL_USERNAME, COL_PASSWORD},
                COL_USERNAME + "=" + username + "'AND" + COL_PASSWORD + "='" + password + "'", null,null,null,null);
            if (myCursor != null) {
            myCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return myCursor;
    }

    private ContentValues createUserTableContentValues(String username, String password) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_USERNAME, username);
        values.put(COL_PASSWORD, password);
        return values;
    }
}
```

Here's the logcat in Android Monitor

```
02-02 01:55:48.439 2659-2659/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
    02-02 01:55:48.585 2659-2659/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack-2/lib/x86
    02-02 01:55:48.639 2659-2672/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
    02-02 01:55:48.725 2659-2672/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    02-02 01:55:48.770 2659-2672/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    02-02 01:55:48.770 2659-2672/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad920680, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    02-02 01:55:49.803 2659-2665/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack W/art: Suspending all threads took: 23.765ms
    02-02 01:55:53.288 2659-2672/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xab9c45a0
    02-02 01:55:54.230 2659-2665/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack W/art: Suspending all threads took: 8.143ms
    02-02 01:55:54.294 2659-2672/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    02-02 01:55:54.294 2659-2672/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad926e60, error=EGL_SUCCESS
    02-02 01:56:08.158 2659-2659/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "'ANDpassword='": syntax error
    02-02 01:56:08.159 2659-2659/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    02-02 01:56:08.159 2659-2659/com.example.ikramhs.shoerack E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.ikramhs.shoerack, PID: 2659
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "'ANDpassword='": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, username, password FROM user WHERE username=therhaman'ANDpassword='091192'
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:887)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
            at com.example.ikramhs.shoerack.DatabaseAdapter.fetchUser(DatabaseAdapter.java:42)
            at com.example.ikramhs.shoerack.welcome.LogMeIn(welcome.java:68)
            at com.example.ikramhs.shoerack.welcome.access$000(welcome.java:17)
            at com.example.ikramhs.shoerack.welcome$1.onClick(welcome.java:46)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
    02-02 01:56:09.955 2659-2659/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2659 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "'ANDpassword='": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT id, username, password FROM user WHERE username=therhaman'ANDpassword='091192'
```

You need a space between AND and password.

Answer (score 0):

Your Logcat is clearly said it "near "'ANDpassword='": syntax error (code 1)".
You have SQL syntax error and I believe it should be "AND password=". Change below line such that it becomes (space after COL_PASSWORD):

```
 COL_USERNAME + "=" + username + "' AND " + COL_PASSWORD + "='" + password + "
```